# htmlContent not working in Magento 2.3.1 from Magento 2.3.0

Tags: uicomponent, magento2.3.1

My custom module stopped loading ui_component based admin form of Magento 2.3.1, because of `<htmlContent name="gallery">` , however it was working fine in Magento 2.3.0. No logs or reports found to follow the problem, only blank page.

Here is the code, which i remove and form load,

```
     <htmlContent name="gallery" sortOrder="22">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="wrapper" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Images</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <wrapper>
            <canShow>true</canShow>
            <componentType>fieldset</componentType>
        </wrapper>
    </settings>
    <block name="gallery" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Gallery">
        <block class="ABC\Categorybanner\Block\Adminhtml\Categorybanner\Edit\Tab\Images" as="content">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="parentComponent" xsi:type="string">categorybanner_index_form.categorybanner_index_form.block_gallery.block_gallery</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>

        </block>
    </block>
</htmlContent>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated in magento version 2.3.1 From Magento 2.3.0

Newly added code in Maegnto 2.3.1 :

`"isResizeEnabled": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getImageUploadConfigData()->getIsResizeEnabled() ?>`

File :

> vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/media/uploader.phtml

That object was not there earlier versions. `$block->getImageUploadConfigData()`